# In dragon vale what habitat does the obsidian dragon live in?

Tags: dragonvale

I just bred this thing and now it says I don’t have the habitat and I don’t know which habitat to buy and I’m so confused.

Answer (score 0):

The obsidian dragon in dragon vale can be placed in a Earth or Fire habitat.

Try this site > http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Obsidian_Dragon

Answer (score -1):

You can use an Earth or fire habitat for an obsidian dragon. For extra help on the Dragon and it will say on the side habitats and under it the habitats needed